# Struggling With DQL and Case When Expression

Tags: php, sql, doctrine, dql

I am attempting the following query and am having some trouble with the **count(CASE WHEN r.status=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)** part.

I really need to capture the count of status's where they are equal to "complete". I tried the following but I keep getting: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer:T_FROM, got '.'

can someone help?

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $query = $em->createQuery(
                            'SELECT count(r.rpId) AS referralCount, count(CASE WHEN r.status=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as referralCompleted, p.firstName, p.lastName, p.npi, u.username
        FROM MainReferralCaptureBundle:Referral r, MainReferralCaptureBundle:Physician p, MainUserBundle:User u
        WHERE r.valid = 1 
        AND r.rpId = p.id
        AND r.submittedBy = u.id
        AND r.createdDate BETWEEN :startdate AND :enddate
        GROUP BY p.id')
                    ->setParameter('startdate', $form->get('startdate')->getData())
                    ->setParameter('enddate',  $form->get('enddate')->getData());
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not grouping by all non-aggregate fields from your `SELECT` statement.  That doesn't cause an error in some rdbms but it does cause results to be rubbish.

Additionally:

```
count(CASE WHEN r.status=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Will count all records due to the `ELSE 0`.  Remove the `ELSE` altogether and it will only count when the condition is met.  Likewise you could change the `ELSE 0` to `ELSE NULL`.  `NULL` is excluded from aggregates.  You could also change `COUNT()` to `SUM()`.

That's all I notice from the query itself, not sure what the error you're getting is about.

Comment: I removed the ELSE and using sum instead of count. Now it says Error Unexpected ')'. :(

Comment: `SUM(CASE WHEN r.status=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`   
and `COUNT(CASE WHEN r.status=2 THEN 1 END)`   should both be fine.

Comment: sum(CASE WHEN r.status = 2 THEN 1 END)

Comment: the query works perfectly other then the fact that I need to get the count of status's where they are equal to a certain value. Its that or write another query which is not optimal :(

Comment: It seems to look at the "." in count(CASE WHEN r.status = 2 THEN 1 END) and break it. When I use sum, it freaks out at the ")"

Comment: @milof Sorry, it looks like Doctrine is a funky beast, I was just thinking standard SQL.

Comment: no worries. I completely understand (and appreciate) your help.